# Is it correct to use the verb "delimit" with the preposition "into"?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

I try to understand whether the verb "delimit" can be used with the preposition "into".

Below is an excerpt from my technical guide about naming files.

> To delimit words, use underscores, not spaces. **To delimit a file name into multiple parts**, use one, two, or three hyphens.
>
> ```
> shakespeare_william---a_midsummer_nights_dream---1595-1596.pdf
> ```

To my ears, it sounds good, but I'm a foreigner, and so I am not really sure that "delimit" can be used in such a way. I see a probability that it should be used in the following way instead:

> To delimit words, use underscores, not spaces. **To delimit different parts of a file name**, use one, two, or three hyphens.
>
> ```
> shakespeare_william---a_midsummer_nights_dream---1595-1596.pdf
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"delimit ... into" sounds natural to me and, according to this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=delimit%20_NOUN_%20into&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdelimit%20_NOUN_%20into%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdelimit%20_NOUN_%20into%3B%2Cc0), its use in publications is growing in popularity. Your alternative suggestion is also acceptable.